# Getting error while checking Custom Label value in IF statement

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-object

I have one **formula field(size__c)** datatype Number .
I am checking in trigger **if (acc.size__c<=system.label.Com_size)**
Here my Custom Label is Com_size and Value is 1000 in custom label.
But I am getting below error

```
Comparison arguments must be compatible types: Decimal, String
```

Pleas suggest.How can I check if condition with custom Label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Label are always String type. You need to cast your Label to a Integer.

```
if (acc.size__c <= Integer.valueOf(system.label.Com_size))
```

Comment: That was an easy one. I knew you would be on that one. Must be fast with you guys haha.

Comment: I was just wandering by, really. I like to get in a few late night answers. Glad to see I'm not the only one!

Comment: sorry for late reply.but its working perfect.Thanks

Comment: You welcome @dem, feel free to mark it as a Answer for other blogger.